# is there a difference between /mnt/sdcard and /sdcard?

Tags: android, android-image, android-file

I'm trying to save a bitmap into the Pictures directory. Here's the code

```
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            File file = new File(path, "test1.PNG");
            try { 
                   path.mkdirs();
                   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
            }
```

But the execution got stuck at `OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);`
I used the debugger and the full path returns `mnt/sdcard/Pictures/test1.PNG`, is `mnt/` the culprit why I couldn't get past `OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);`? Because I can only see `sdcard/` in my file directory.

thanks!

Comment: What is the value of 'path'..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and access the sdcard directory using this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` as the mnt/sdcard or sdcard/ its an device dependent directory that how OS was access and use the external directory no need to worry for different device and different directory was return by this method.

**EDIT**

For accessing external storage need permission and define in `androidmanifest.xml` file as user permission

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: thanks alot for your reply, appreciate the time. apparently for it to work one must set the permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, I overlooked this part and hence the FileNotFoundException even after mkdir() is called.

Answer (score 3):

`/sdcard` is a softlink to `/mnt/sdcard`...
and `/sdcard` is read only in file system so better use `/mnt/sdcard/`..

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 String filePath = "/sdcard/yourfile.txt";

 FileOutputStream os = null;
 os = new FileOutputStream(filePath); 
 os.write(write it to file);
 os.close();
```